# How to provide headers and authenticate at server site using FASTAPI request?

Tags: javascript, python, header, fastapi, request-headers

I am trying to build a data ploting app, when I request data from the javascript to uvicorn server using fastAPI, browser throws CORS error related to headers. I tried  to  provide headers as given  bellow but not sure how to authonticate them at  server side using  fastAPI.

**JavaScript:**

```
  var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/data';

  $.ajax({
  url: url,
  type:'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  beforeSend: setHeader,
  // data: data,
  success: function(response) {
    chartCircle.updateSeries([
      response.q
    ],
    console.log(response.q)
    )

  }
});


function setHeader(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader('securityCode', 'Foo');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('passkey', 'Bar');
}
```

**Python:**  FAST-API

```
from typing import Optional
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import random

app = FastAPI()

origins = [*]

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get("/data")
def read_item( q: Optional[str] = None):

    return { "q": random.uniform(2.5, 10.0) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled and configured cors on your FastAPI config?
It would look something like this:

```
app = FastAPI()
origins = [
  "http://localhost:8080",
]

app.add_middleware(
  CORSMiddleware,
  allow_origins=origins,
  allow_credentials=True,
  allow_methods=["*"],
  allow_headers=["*"],
)
```